# Run a completablefuture on same thread as executing thread or on a different thread

Tags: java, multithreading, future, completable-future

I have the following class which runs a `FutureTask` on the same thread as the thread that starts the `FutureTask`.

Is there a way to achieve this using a `CompletableFuture`?

I ask because I would eventually like to take advantage of chaining multiple `CompletableFuture`s together. With the ability of specifying whether they run on the same thread as the executing thread or on a different thread.

```
public class SameThreadFutureTask {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
    Callable<String> action = new Callable<String>() {
      public String call() {
        try {
          Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "hello "+Thread.currentThread();
      }
    };
    System.out.println("before");

    FutureTask<String> ft = new FutureTask<>(action);
    ft.run();
    System.out.println(ft.get());
    System.out.println("After");
  }
}
```

Which produces the following output:

```
Thread[main,5,main]
before
hello Thread[main,5,main]
After
```

Comment: `CompletableFuture::XXX` method (like `runAsync/supplyAsync`, etc) have an overloaded method that takes an `Executor` as the last parameter - which you can use in your case

Answer (score 3):

You can construct a `new CompletableFuture<>()` without any completion and chain as many operations as you like. Then, at the point you know how you want to complete it, call `complete` for a completion in the same thread or `completeAsync` for an asynchronous completion.

```java
final String main = Thread.currentThread().getName();

for(boolean sameThread: new boolean[] { true, false}) {
    System.out.println("will use " + (sameThread? "same thread ("+main+")": "async"));

    CompletableFuture<String> initial = new CompletableFuture<>();
    CompletableFuture<?> result = initial
        .thenApply(s -> {
            System.out.println("toUpperCase in " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            return s.toUpperCase();
        })
        .thenAccept(s -> System.out.println(
            "final processing of \"" + s + "\" in " + Thread.currentThread().getName()));

    System.out.println("before");
    if(sameThread) {
        initial.complete("hello " + main);
    }
    else {
        initial.completeAsync(() -> "hello " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
    System.out.println("after");

    result.join();
    System.out.println();
}
```

This demonstrates both modes.

```
will use same thread (main)
before
toUpperCase in main
final processing of "HELLO MAIN" in main
after

will use async
before
after
toUpperCase in ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1
final processing of "HELLO FORKJOINPOOL.COMMONPOOL-WORKER-1" in ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1
```

---

Note that `completeAsync` has been introduced in Java 9. If you need a similar construct in Java 8, you have to replace
`initial.completeAsync(() -> "hello " + Thread.currentThread().getName());` with

```java
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
    try {
        initial.complete("hello " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    } catch(Throwable t) {
        initial.completeExceptionally(t);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Executor sameThreadExecutor = runnable -> runnable.run();
Runnable myTask = () -> System.out.println("hello "+Thread.currentThread());
CompletableFuture.runAsync(myTask, sameThreadExecutor).get();
```

---

> With the ability of specifying whether they run on the same thread as the executing thread or on a different thread.

```
boolean useSameThread = ...;
Executor sameThreadExecutor = runnable -> runnable.run();
Executor forkJoin = ForkJoinPool.commonPool();
Executor preferredExecutor = useSameThread ? sameThreadExecutor : forkJoin;
Runnable hello = () -> System.out.println("hello "+Thread.currentThread());
Runnable helloAgain = () -> System.out.println("hello again " + Thread.currentThread());
Runnable bye = () -> System.out.println("bye " + Thread.currentThread());
CompletableFuture.runAsync(hello, preferredExecutor)
    .thenRunAsync(helloAgain, preferredExecutor)
    .thenRunAsync(bye, preferredExecutor)
    .get();
```